# Magento2: How to add modal inside my module like customer address modal?

Tags: magento2

How to add modal form inside my module like customer address modal?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your custom module phtml you can use the code below to display Modal box.

```
<a id="myModel-opener"  href="#">Click Here to open Modal</a>
<div id="myModel" style="display:none;" >
<div class="mymodal-box">
    Lorem ipsum.......
   </div>
```

```
    <script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };
            var popup = modal(options, $('#myModel'));
            $("#myModel-opener").on('click',function(){
                $("#myModel").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: How to create form inside modal and save the form using insertform tag? like customer address option.. In backend

Comment: Anyone know how to use insert form tag like customer address? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the code below to create form inside Modal

```
<a id="myModel-opener"  href="#">Click Here to open Modal</a>
<div id="myModel" style="display:none;" >
<div class="mymodal-box">
<form action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'yourrouter/index/post/';?>" name="customepopupForm" class="form register" method="post" id="form-validate" data-hasrequired="<?php echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
   <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend"><span>My Modal Form</span></legend>            
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="field fullname required">
                    <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo __('Name') ?>"  placeholder="<?php echo __('Name') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="field email required">
                    <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" placeholder="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="field telephone required">
                    <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="phone" id="phone" title="<?php echo __('Phone') ?>" placeholder="<?php echo __('Phone') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="field comment required">
                    <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Message')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" title="<?php echo __('Message') ?>" placeholder="<?php echo __('Message') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- For Submit Button inside Form-->
    <!--<div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>-->
    <span id='ajax_loader1' style='display:none'>
            <img src="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl(); ?>pub/media/home/loader-1.gif" style="height: 150px;width: 150px">
    </span>    
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#form-validate": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<script>

    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function($,modal) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title:'My Custom Popup Form',
                closeText: 'Close',

                buttons: [{
                  text: $.mage.__('Close'),
            class: 'cls',

            /**
             * Click handler.
             */
            click: function (event) {
                this.closeModal(event);
            }
        },{
                    text: $.mage.__('Submit'),
                    class: 'sbt',
                    click: function (data) {
                        if ($('#form-validate').valid()) {
                        var form_data = jQuery("#form-validate").serialize();
                        jQuery('#ajax_loader1').show();

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'yourrouter/index/post/';?>",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data : form_data,
                            success: function(data){
                              //alert(data);

                                jQuery('#ajax_loader1').hide();
                               var msg = JSON.parse(data);
                               //alert(msg.message.msg);
                               $(".message").empty();
                               if(msg.message.code===0){
                               $(".message").append(msg.message.msg).css( "color", "red" );
                                }else{
                                $(".message").append(msg.message.msg).css( "color", "green" );  
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(result){
                                console.log('no response !');
                                $(".message").empty();
                                $(".message").append('no response !');
                            }
                        });
                        }else{

                        return false;
                        }                       

                    }
                }],
                /**
                 * Escape key press handler,
                 * close modal window
                 */
                escapeKey: function () {
                    if (this.options.isOpen && this.modal.find(document.activeElement).length ||
                        this.options.isOpen && this.modal[0] === document.activeElement) {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }
            };
            var popup = modal(options, $('#myModel'));
            $("#myModel-opener").on('click',function(){
                $("#myModel").modal("openModal");
            });



        }
    );



</script>
```

Comment: ok sir thank you, where have to call this  file? Can you please explain

Comment: Can you  explain me please, How to save this form in database?